# Do any classes benefit from Paragon/Renegade scores?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do any classes benefit from a Paragon or Renegade reputation gameplay-wise?

Reputation used to affect the [Intimidation/Charm skills](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Intimidate#Intimidate) in previous games, so I'm wondering if there's any class-related skills/ect that are affected by reputation in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but it does go the other way around. Every class has a unique skill which increases your Reputation score at several ranks, in addition to other, class specific benefits.